# Specific reference request for category theory

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

What are some textbook that contain material about monoidal categories and monoid objects? I have seen Awodey's and Riehl's books and they don't seem to cover this part, while Mac Lane is way too dense to be used for my course. I accept even other kind of sources, like sites or online lectures, but  I have to exclude nLab because it uses higher category theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some resources on monoidal categories (including monoid objects) which I found quite useful and detailed as a beginner:

- P. Etingof, S. Gelaki, D. Nikshych, V. Ostrik. **Tensor Categories**, Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, Vol. 205. [Link](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/egnobookfinal.pdf) **(Chapter 2)**
- N. Saavedra-Rivano. **Categories Tannakiennes**, Lectures Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 265, Springer, 1972. [Link](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540058441) **(Chapter 1)**
- F. Borceux. **Handbook of Categorical Algebra: Volume 1, Basic
  Category Theory**, volume 50 of Encyclopedia of Mathematics and
  its Applications. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1994. [Link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/handbook-of-categorical-algebra/A0B8285BBA900AFE85EED8C971E0DE14) **(Chapter 7)**

Borceux "only" treats bicategories, but monoidal categories are just one-object bicategories, and general bicategories are not much more difficult to understand.

In case you know German, you can also check out [my book](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783662535202) which treats monoidal categories in depth.

Comment: Since the OP finds Mac Lane "way too dense", I fear these suggestions will be way way too dense.